# Compare 2 tables and show 1 column answer

Tags: ms-access

I have been trying to do a phone number comparison from 2 different tables. 
For Example

```
Area 1:
Customer_ Tel:
10123
10020

Area 2: 
Customer_Tel:
02103
02351
10123
```

Using Area 1 as the reference, I wanted the outcome to show numbers in Area 2 which could not be found ( or match) with Table 1.

I tried using this:

```
Select Area1.[customer_tel],Area2.[customer_tel]
From Area1
Left Join Area 2
On Area1.[customer_id]=Area2.[customer_tel]
```

The query above identified numbers that could be found in Area 1 and it went on to show in show in Area 2, customer ID column.
Following I add in using the WHERE Area1. [customer_tel]<>Area2.[customer_tel] 
which showed all blank cells except for the headers.

Hope some kind soul would help in tweaking it.

Comment: If I understand you correctly then you need RIGHT JOIN rather than Left Join in the query. `Select Area1.[customer_tel],Area2.[customer_tel] From Area1 Right Join Area 2 On Area1.[customer_id]=Area2.[customer_tel]`

Comment: Also, your WHERE clause is wrong, I suppose. Please try the query given here. `Select Area1.[customer_tel],Area2.[customer_tel] From Area1 Right Join Area 2 On Area1.[customer_tel]=Area2.[customer_tel]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this with JOINS. The following is a LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT Area2.[customer_tel]
FROM Area2
LEFT JOIN Area1 ON Area1.[customer_tel]=Area2.[customer_tel]
WHERE Area1.[customer_tel] IS NULL
```

While this here is a RIGHT JOIN

```
SELECT Area2.[customer_tel]
FROM Area1
RIGHT JOIN Area2 ON Area2.[customer_tel] = Area1.[customer_tel]
WHERE Area1.[customer_tel] IS NULL
```

Both result in the same number of records while 'starting' from a different table.